# Importing CSV-file as list returns empty list

Tags: python

This issue is making me go nuts.

I want to import a CSV-file row by row.

I tried the following code:

```
import csv

def read_file():
    with open ('filepath', 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';') 
        data=[] 
        for rad in csv_reader: 
            data.append(rad) 

read_file()
print(data)
```

When trying to print data, I get the following error message:

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject11/venv/bin/python /Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject11/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 12, in <module>
    print(data)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

if I define data=[] after import csv and before def read_file() the code works. However, I need data to be defined within the function read_file.

Any suggestions?

The data looks as following:

```
[['', '2018', '2018', '2015', '2015', '2012', '2012', '2009', '2009', '2006', '2006', '2003', '2003', '2018', '2015', '2012', '2009', '2006', '2003'], ['', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'medel', 'medel', 'medel', 'medel', 'medel', 'medel'], ['Australia', '494', '488', '497', '491', '510', '498', '519', '509', '527', '513', '527', '522', '491', '494', '504', '514', '520', '524'], ['Austria', '505', '492', '510', '483', '517', '494', '506', '486', '517', '494', '509', '502', '499', '497', '506', '496', '505', '506']]
```

Comment: `return` the data from the function? `data` is just a local variable. You need to get it to the global scope. Add a `return data` as the last line of the function and then call it like `data = read_file()`

Comment: You need to `return data`

Comment: By the way you don't need a loop here. It can just be `data = list(csv_reader)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo That worked. Amazing how I overlooked it. Thank you. If you post your answer I will declare it as working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a variable declared inside a function is only available inside that function and not in the global scope. In this case my suggestion would be to return the data from the function after you have finished reading the file. In other words something like this:

```py
import csv

def read_file():
    with open ('filepath', 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';') 
        data=[] 
        for rad in csv_reader: 
            data.append(rad)

    return data

file_data = read_file()
print(file_data)
```

It is also possible to make the `data` variable inside the function global, however this is normally not recommended due to global variables quickly becoming hard to keep track of, it is much easier to see where data is coming from when it is returned from a function like this.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code (shown below) to return the data variable from the function:

```
import csv

def read_file():
    with open ('filepath', 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';') 
        data = [] 
        for rad in csv_reader: 
            data.append(rad) 

        return data

data = read_file()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare data as a global variable outside the function. Currently `data` is only seen in the scope of the function but it's not seen outside the function where you print it. You can learn more about python scopes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

```
import csv

data=[]

def read_file():
    with open ('filepath', 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')  
        for rad in csv_reader: 
            data.append(rad) 

read_file()
print(data)
```

Comment: It is better to avoid that where possible. This makes for unclear code (`read_file` modifying some data instead of returning it) and relies on some variables being declared before-hand